# Trouble inserting Chinese characters from a CSV into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

I'm trying to write a PHP script that loops through a CSV and inserts the values from the CSV to a MySQL table. The characters look fine in the CSV, but when I insert them into the database, they show up as`ç‹‚å¹²` and variants.

I have the PDO connection set to a UTF-8 charset, the table itself is set to UTF-8, and when I dump the characters, they show as the correct Chinese characters, as long as I set the UTF-8 header. However, they go all wonky on insert, and remain so when selecting them back out. If I use a GUI (Navicat) to insert a particular phrase, it selects out fine.

```
$mysql = new PDO('mysql:host=1.2.3.4;dbname=db;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$handle = fopen('bannedWords.csv', 'r');
$count = 0;
$word = '';
$insert = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO sensitivePhrases SET phrase = :word");
$insert->bindParam(':word', $word);
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
    $word = $data[1];
    var_dump($word);
    $insert->execute();
}
```

I've tried using `uft8_encode` and `utf8_decode`, as well as `mb_convert_encoding`, none of which have helped. I'd love some advice on where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your MySQL you need to specify `utf8mb4` because while UTF-8 in the rest of the universe is a 4-byte index, in MySQL it's only a 3-byte index, so only displays a small subset of all UTF-8 characters.

```
$mysql = new PDO('mysql:host=1.2.3.4;dbname=db;charset=utf8mb4', 'username', 'password');
```

You need to apply `utf8mb4` to both your connection as well as your destination table.

Read the Excellent [StackOveflow post about UTF-8 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Sorry about that; I realize I may not have tried it in my connection and will respond again after I try it.

Comment: Success! I must have not added it in my connection! It worked!

Comment: Yah, sorry, last night it wasn't letting me check for some reason; thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any form of encode/decode function.

Do not read the lines one at a time; instead use `LOAD DATA ... CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 ...;`

If the data is not arranged correctly for the new schema, either fiddle with @variables inside the `LOAD` statement or load into a tmp table, then do some transforms.

Meanwhile, you *should not* need to convert characters anywhere; simply specify the correct character set everywhere.

If you have more trouble, let's see the hex of some characters (together with what you expect).  And let's see `LOAD ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.